# Linq for "List<Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, object>>>" order the values by asc

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I would like to order all elements

This is the way I can iterate through it:

```
 List<Dictionary<string, object>> valueList = ((IEnumerable<object>)y.Value).Select(x => (Dictionary<string, object>)x).ToList();
 foreach (Dictionary<string, object> dict in valueList)
 {
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in dict)
   {

   }
 }
```

I have huge problems with forming a LINQ-expression, which will order all the values to a specific key.(For example, I have special key and that value I want to reorder the entire data source)

```
valueList.OrderBy(ya => (ya.Values as List<Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, object>>>).Keys.First(key => key.Equals("propertyToSearchFor")));
```

I get:

> Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.ValueCollection'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>>'
>   via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion,
>   wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

What should  it be instead ?

***UPDATED 1***

Thanks for answering, this is an example of the data I use http://i63.tinypic.com/2d0mhb9.png .

I have my `valueList`, which I need to  reorder, depending on the key "propertyToSearchFor"(take a look at the screenshot: "modell","marke" or ..., "jan"). For example `valueList[0]` contains some kind of data set, which has the same key's in `valueList[1]`, but the value in `valueList[1]` are different than in `valueList[0]`.

I need to order the data resource by "modell" it should go through all elements in  `valueList[...]` and reorder that list depending on the value of modell.

***UPDATED 2***

Here is something for copy and paste :)

```
 List<Dictionary<string, object>> valueList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

                                       valueList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() 
                                           { 
                                             {"property1", "test"},
                                             {"property2", null}, 
                                             {"property3", new Object()}, 
                                             {"property4", 34.0f}, 
                                             {"property5", 5.0d}, 
                                             {"property6", 'c'}, 
                                             {"property7", "xtest"}, 
                                             {"property8", "gtest"}, 
                                             {"property9", "jtest"}, 
                                             {"property10", "1ptest"}, 
                                             {"property11", "atest"}, 
                                             {"property12", "test"}, 
                                             {"property13", "ätest"}, 
                                             {"property14", "test"}, 
                                             {"property15", "ztest"}, 

                                           });

                                       valueList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() 
                                           { 
                                             {"property1", "test"},
                                             {"property2", null}, 
                                             {"property3", new Object()}, 
                                             {"property4", 342.0f}, 
                                             {"property5", 25.0d}, 
                                             {"property6", 'h'}, 
                                             {"property7", "1xtest"}, 
                                             {"property8", "gtest"}, 
                                             {"property9", "1jtest"}, 
                                             {"property10", "1ptest"}, 
                                             {"property11", "atest"}, 
                                             {"property12", "1test"}, 
                                             {"property13", "1ätest"}, 
                                             {"property14", "test"}, 
                                             {"property15", "ztest"}, 

                                           });

                                       valueList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() 
                                           { 
                                             {"property1", "test"},
                                             {"property2", null}, 
                                             {"property3", new Object()}, 
                                             {"property4", 344.0f}, 
                                             {"property5", 5.0d}, 
                                             {"property6", 'z'}, 
                                             {"property7", "xtest"}, 
                                             {"property8", "gt213est"}, 
                                             {"property9", "jtest"}, 
                                             {"property10", "2311ptest"}, 
                                             {"property11", "21atest"}, 
                                             {"property12", "321test"}, 
                                             {"property13", "231ätest"}, 
                                             {"property14", "31test"}, 
                                             {"property15", "z231test"}, 

                                           });

                                       valueList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() 
                                           { 
                                             {"property1", "test"},
                                             {"property2", null}, 
                                             {"property3", new Object()}, 
                                             {"property4", 3.0f}, 
                                             {"property5", 500.0d}, 
                                             {"property6", 'z'}, 
                                             {"property7", "xtest"}, 
                                             {"property8", "gstest"}, 
                                             {"property9", "jtest"}, 
                                             {"property10", "1pstest"}, 
                                             {"property11", "atsest"}, 
                                             {"property12", "test"}, 
                                             {"property13", "ätsest"}, 
                                             {"property14", "tesst"}, 
                                             {"property15", "ztsest"}, 

                                           });
```

Comment: is y defined as `var y = new KeyValuePair < string, object>("1",1);` for example?

Comment: please text, I can't open the image link, thanks

Comment: What type is `y`?

Comment: do you really have to use type object for the second generic parameter?

Comment: @Radinator yes I have to use `object`, because these key/value paires come from an object using reflection

Comment: updated my post, thanks for support

Comment: what irritates me, is that you keep your - already  - collection in a collection...List<Dictionary<T1, T2>>. this makes nearly no sense. In the Dicionary there is already a Collection with KeyValuePair. If you remove the outer Collection, the LINQ query should be more easily to make

Comment: @Radinator this is a given structure, I can't change it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the `OfType` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
valueList.OrderBy(ya => ya.Values.OfType<Dictionary<string,object>>().First(key => key.Equals("propertyToSearchFor")));
```

**After** your **update2**

```
   var test = valueList.Select(x => new { a=x,  b=x["property4"] })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.b).Select(x=>x.a).ToList();
```

in case you want to manage a *non existing key* (to avoid the exception)

```
   Func<string,Dictionary<string,object>,object> func = (s,x) => { object o = null; x.TryGetValue(s, out o); return o; };
   var test = valueList.Select(x => new { a=x,  b = func("nonExisting",x)})
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.b).Select(x=>x.a).ToList();
```

So the following is ordering  your `valueList` in update2 (descending) by an (existing) `property5`

```
var testProperty5Desc = valueList.Select(x => new { a=x,  b = func("property5",x)})
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.b).Select(x=>x.a).ToList();
```

Comment: @ASfdsa33 I need a text code example  to produce valueList or alternatively y and then valueList. Don't post images, thanks

Comment: no, i get something like "the key does not exist in the dictionary" ...

Comment: @ASfdsa33 updated again to avoid the exception for non existing keys... I've tested with your valueList in update2 and it is ordering it

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I still can not see it working the right way  for example, if I order by "property7" I will get "xtest,1xtest,xtest,xtest" but it should be more "xtest,xtest,xtest,1xtest" or ordering by "property5" I will be the wrong order the result is "5,25,5,500" ... (actually the same order I declared/defined the objects)

Comment: Are you looking at var test ?? valueList itself is not ordered of course! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if `valueList` is a `List<T>` with `T` being a `Dictionary<string, object>`there is no member `Values`, or am I missing anything? The current element `ya` already *is* a `Dictionary<string, object>`, so you won´t need to cast it:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> valueList = ...
var result = valueList.OrderBy(ya => ya.Keys.First(key => key.Equals("propertyToSearchFor")));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the variable `ya` is an element of `valueList`.
So it's a `Dictionary<string, object>` type.
So this line of code should work.

```
valueList.OrderBy(ya => ya.Values.First(key => key.Equals("propertyToSearchFor")));
```